# how to set system wide proxy address in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS server

Tags: server, 18.04

I install ubuntu server 18.04 LTS distribution without specifying the proxy address during installation and I am having a challenge in setting the systemwide proxy address...

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
sudo vi /etc/environment
```

and add the following lines to the environment file just below to the PATH line

```
http_proxy="http://userName:password@proxy:port"
https_proxy="http://userName:password@proxy:port"
ftp_proxy="http://userName:password@proxy:port"
```

where username and password are optional. After writing press the escape key and type `:wq` and press <kbd>enter</kbd> to save and exit the editor.

In the terminal run the following command

```
sudo netplan apply
```

It works for me...